# What is the value of the composite zeta function evaluated at 2?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, zeta-functions

This is my very first question on this website.
I was trying to calculate the value of ζ(4). Although I know the exact value (which I found on google to be pi^4/90) but I wanted to derive it by myself. While doing so, I arrived at this rather peculiar expression:
$C = \frac{7ℼ^4}{720} - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{P}{2}$

where C is the value of the composite zeta function at 2 and P is the prime zeta function at 2.
My question is this. What will be the value of C? I am getting 0.22090911477. Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming

$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n}\frac{1}{n^s}$$

$$P(s)=\sum_{p\text{ prime}}\frac{1}{p^s}$$

$$\mathcal C(s)=\sum_{n\text{ composite}}\frac{1}{n^s}$$

then

$$\mathcal C(s)=\zeta(s)-P(s)-1$$

and

$$\mathcal C(2)=\zeta(2)-P(2)-1=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-P(2)-1\approx 0.192687$$